# Comparable Interface

Tags: java, interface, comparable

Why is it beneficial to implement the `Comparable` interface instead of just defining my own `compareTo()` method?

Another thing, how does the `java.util.Arrays.sort(Object[] o)` method relate to the `Comparable` interface such that I HAVE to implement the Comparable interface to be able to use the `Arrays.sort(Object[] o)` method?

Comment: Did you mean creating ur own method to sort any list of object instead using comparable ??

Comment: I mean creating my own compareTo method instead of overriding the compareTo method in the Comparable interface.

Comment: U have to make the algo inside compareTo to sort it, bcoz thn u cant use Collections/Arrays sort method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it beneficial to implement the Comparable interface instead of
>   just defining my own compareTo method?

You can define your own method, but all the classes, which need to compare must know it. Comparable is there in Java api for this purpose and all peoples know it well. Comparable interface is a super type for many classes, regardless of their origin. So, it's commonly used in all major frameworks.

> Another thing, how does the java.util.Arrays.sort(Object[] o) method
>   relate to the Comparable interface such that I HAVE to implement the
>   Comparable interface to be able to use the Arrays.sort(Object[] o)
>   method?

`Arrays.sort()` method internally calls the `compareTo()` method of `Comparable` classes to sort the content.

Check the source code of [`Arrays.sort()`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html), the delegating method use the `Comparabble#compareTo()` method

```
private static void mergeSort(Object[] src,
                  Object[] dest,
                  int low,
                  int high,
                  int off) {
    int length = high - low;

    // Insertion sort on smallest arrays
        if (length < INSERTIONSORT_THRESHOLD) {
            for (int i=low; i<high; i++)
                for (int j=i; j>low &&
             ((Comparable) dest[j-1]).compareTo(dest[j])>0; j--)
                    swap(dest, j, j-1);
            return;
        }

        // Recursively sort halves of dest into src
        int destLow  = low;
        int destHigh = high;
        low  += off;
        high += off;
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        mergeSort(dest, src, low, mid, -off);
        mergeSort(dest, src, mid, high, -off);

        // If list is already sorted, just copy from src to dest.  This is an
        // optimization that results in faster sorts for nearly ordered lists.
        if (((Comparable)src[mid-1]).compareTo(src[mid]) <= 0) {
            System.arraycopy(src, low, dest, destLow, length);
            return;
        }

        // Merge sorted halves (now in src) into dest
        for(int i = destLow, p = low, q = mid; i < destHigh; i++) {
            if (q >= high || p < mid && ((Comparable)src[p]).compareTo(src[q])<=0)
                dest[i] = src[p++];
            else
                dest[i] = src[q++];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ur second answer is correct but first answer dont explain properly.Can u explain in more easier way

Comment: just one more question.Did you mean that OP can create method whose responsibility is to sort the objects ?? If yes thn thnks for updated

Comment: @NiksTyagi : Yes, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still having trouble getting my head around the true benefit of implementing Comparable interface. Could you perhaps give me insight(possibly provide some code) as to how Arrays.sort(Object[] o) invokes the compareTo method?

Comment: @Schalk open the code of Arrays.sort, u will understand it much better way

Comment: @Schalk : Answer Updated, check it

Comment: Great, I fully understand the purpose of it now. Thank you for all your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Done, have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

The Comparable Interface lets you sort lists and arrays of objects. If you want to sort instances of your class through Collections.sort() method you need to Implement this Interface. For example you can easily sort instances of String using the sort() method that is because String Implements Comparable Interface and the Interface has a single method compareTo() which is invoked each time we are sorting String Instances. Similarly you can use it your own way for sorting Instances of your class by implementing Comparable and overriding its method CompareTo().

Answer (score 1):

```
// below is the example to override the CompareTo() method
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DVDInfo implements Comparable<DVDInfo>{
    String title;
    String genre;
    String LeadActor;
    List<DVDInfo> dvdList=new ArrayList<DVDInfo>();

    public DVDInfo(String t, String g,String a) {
        title=t;
        genre=g;
        LeadActor=a;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return("Title: "+ title +" Genere: " +genre + " LeadActor: " +LeadActor );
    }
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
    public String getGenre()
    {
        return genre;
    }
    public String getLeadActor()
    {
        return LeadActor;
    }

    public void addList(DVDInfo d)
    {
        dvdList.add(d);

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void populateList()
    {
            Collections.sort(dvdList);
            System.out.println(dvdList);

    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(DVDInfo d) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return title.compareTo(d.getTitle());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DVDInfo d=new DVDInfo("Conjuring","Horror","Patrik Wilson");
        DVDInfo e=new DVDInfo("Insidious", "Horror", "Patrik Wilson");

        d.addList(d);
                d.addList(e);
                d.populateList();

    }

    }


    enter code here
```